# When does civicrm-webform remove you from groups?

Tags: webform-civicrm, groups

If you use civicrm-webform, you can add civigroups to your form. You can choose 'user select' to have the user select one or more groups. In the form component, you can choose 'static' to show only a few of all possible groups.

So say you have two newsletter groups and two agegroups. You use the above method to only show the newsletter groups to existing contacts.

Will that remove the the contact from the agegroups if s/he fills out the form ?

Comment: Sounds like you might be able to answer your own question with a quick test of a simple scenario such as you describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webform-CiviCRM will remove you from a group:

- Only if you are logged-in or following a checksum (or otherwise selected as an existing contact)
- Only if the group is presented on the webform as a checkbox/multiselect field and you deselect it.

In other words, the user has to make an active choice. Filling out the form as an unknown user, you're not consciously choosing to *un* check the box (it just defaults that way) so in that instance the module will only add, not remove you from groups.

BTW it works that way for all webform fields. The module will not delete any data from a contact record unless that contact has already been identified and the data was pre-filled on the form and the user made an active choice to erase it.

Comment: @Colman so if the group isn't displays, it should not remove the contact from the group, correct?

Comment: Thanks Coleman! I tested this before I asked the question :-) I just wanted someone who really knew - you - to confirm this, for future users and future releases.

Comment: @YossiCrm yes, this is what I tested. Groups that don't show up in the form are not modified on the contact.