# Subscribe to group via a webform - pass in group Id

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'm using Drupal, CiviCRM, CiviCRM Entity and Webform CiviCRM.

My hope is to link an "activity" (described on a Drupal node) to a group ("Sign up for news about this activity").

So the Group Id would be stored in a field on the Drupal node, and when I click "Sign up" I'm taken to a form where I can sign up to that group.

Is there a way of doing that with Webform CiviCRM?

I've tried setting "Enable Tags and Groups Fields" to "Yes" but I can't see how to pass in the Group Id.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code I wrote to achieve my goal ...

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form['#id'], 'webform-client-form-') === 0) {
    if (in_array(
      'default-via-parameter',
      $form['submitted']['mailing_list']['civicrm_1_contact_1_other_group']['#attributes']['class'])
    ) {
      $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
      if (filter_var($params['gid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1)))) {
        $form['submitted']['mailing_list']['civicrm_1_contact_1_other_group']['#default_value'] = array($params['gid']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Details ...

- Check if it's the right form
- Check that I want to allow the default to be overwritten (via a CSS class attached to the field)
- Check if the Group Id is supplied as an argument, and is valid
- Set the default group to the one supplied

The form can be used without supplying a default to choose any group.
If a default is supplied the user can use this, or even override it

Comment: That looks good, just be careful of one "gotcha" which is that if the user is already a member of other groups, this will remove them!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @coleman! In my test environment, I'm not seeing that my contact is being unsubscribed from other groups.

Comment: The gotcha @Coleman is referring to is described at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/17139/169 and in my case I'm offering a form that doesn't get it's 'contact 1' from an existing contact.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use webform_civicrm? You can inject Markup elements on a webform to dress up you page; and then with Groups -> - User Select - you can get complete control over what Groups people can select from and you can customize their label:

First add Groups to your form in the webform tab:

[image]

Hit Edit on the Webform Element (labeled Group):

[image]

On the form it looks like this - and you can even change the Label for Group(s) to Newsletter(s)

[image]

Comment: Karin, that's what I'm doing. What I'm wanting to do is control which of the groups are selected when the form loads, ideally by passing in the Group Id as a URL parameter.

Comment: Why not let the user select? If you want to you could have a page with buttons -> Newsletter A click here etc and then have a different webform to for each of your Newsletters - but why not show them all in one form and let the user decide which one(s they can select from a preselected list - that you've decided on in your webform Element?

Comment: Karin, there are too many groups to make that a nice UX for the user. I could have N webforms each with M options, but that starts being a maintenance headache.

Comment: You have M times N different Newsletter Groups? (you can remove all non Newsletter groups from the UI from being listed in the Webform element); How many Newsletter groups do you have? There is no way to pass &gid into a webform - but if there was - people would have to go to all webforms one at a time to subscribe if they wanted to subscribe to more than one?